# An interesting open subset of a scheme X.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $(X,O_X)$ scheme and  $f\in{O_X(X)}$ then  $X_f$ is an  open subset of $X$ where
$X_f=\left\{{x\in{X}| f_x\in{u(O_{X,x})}}\right\}$ and $ u(O_{X,x})$is the set of invertible elements.

proof:

Let   $x\in{X_f}$ arbitrary  and  want  to  prove that there is an open neighborhood $W$ of  $x$ such that  $W\subseteq{X_f}$.

As $x\in{X_f}$ then $f_x\in{u(O_{X,x})}$ then there is a $g_x\in{u(O_{X,x})}$
 such that $f_xg_x=1$ .   How I prove that $f_xg_x=(fg)_x$??

Answer (score 1):

*Welcome to Math.SE!* In general, please provide more context to your question (in particular where it comes from - class exercise, book exercise, ...?) and take care of grammar and formatting.

*Concerning your question:* Note that $g_x$ at first only exists as an element of the stalk ${\mathscr O}_{X,x}$, so that it doesn't make sense to speak about $(fg)_x$ in the beginning. What you need to do first is to unfold the definition of the stalk ${\mathscr O}_{X,x}$ in order to *represent* $g_x$ by some function $g_U$ defined in a neighborhood $U$ of $x$. Then you can at least ask whether $f_x g_x = 1_x$ implies $f_U g_U=1_U$. It turns out that this is not the case, but you can achieve it by potentially shrinking $U$. Do you want to try this on your own?

Comment: Thank you.
You can try it?

Comment: Where are you having problems following?

Comment: I do not know where to start

Comment: First things first: Do you understand what I have written? Are you familiar with the definition of stalks and the way functions give rise to elements in the respective stalk and vice versa?

Comment: If I understand the definition of stalk.
I'm reading qing liu.

Comment: @tomás Thanks for deleting the other answers - but can you add your new thoughts to the original question?

Comment: @tomás Did you make progress here?